# Binding using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

In my project I wanna change the background of a Datagrid cell whenever a new Bid price comes in.
And I set it using

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public bool BidUp
{
    get { return _bidUp; }
    set
    {
        _bidUp = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("BidUp");
    }
}
public double Bid
{
    get { return _bid; }
    set
    {
        BidUp = (value > this.Bid);
        _bid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bid");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
```

And my xaml code for the DataGridCell:

```
<DataTemplate>
<Border x:Name="BidBoder" Background="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bid}" x:Name="BidTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
</Border>
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BidUp}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bidUpStoryboard"/>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bidDownStoryboard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="bidUpStoryboard">
                <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00">
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                        To="LimeGreen" 
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="BidBoder" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BidUp}" Value="False">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bidUpStoryboard"/>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="bidDownStoryboard"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="bidDownStoryboard">
                <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00">
                    <ColorAnimation 
                        BeginTime="00:00:00"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" 
                        To="Red" 
                        AutoReverse="True"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="BidBoder" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Now what happens is if price goes up followed by a up, `BidUp = true--->true` the propertyChanged does not trigger. Is there a way to trigeer a change even the `_bidUp = value` does not change?
 And I wanna ask generally if `Property A = somevalue` is called, why `OnPropertyChanged` is not called if the same value applies?

Comment: Can you add your XAML code here?,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Added, but xaml's not related here.

Comment: Are you inheriting from `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Can you post the code of its implementation, and `OnNotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: You need to have a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface and define your properties in that class and it should work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of triggering the update of more than one property in the same setter:

```
public double Bid
{
    get { return _bid; }
    set
    {
        BidUp = (value > this.Bid);
        _bid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bid");
        OnPropertyChanged("BidUp"); // notify both properties in the same setter
    }
}
```

or yet

```
public double Bid
{
    get { return _bid; }
    set
    {
        BidUp = (value > this.Bid);
        _bid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(null); // notify change of EVERY property - good if few properties in ViewModel
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll use the first way.

Comment: Sir Could you have a look again; Actually I found out `OnPropertyChanged("Bid");OnPropertyChanged("Bid");` does not help solve the problem. If `BidUp = true` followed by another Bid price goes up, the notification does not happen. The same case goes gor a false followed by a false

Comment: When the property is true and then true again, technically it did not change value, so I would not expect a property change event.

Comment: @Hans But technically even with the same value,the set accessor `= value` should worked? Any ideas how to work around this problem?

Comment: I did not notified "Bid" twice. One notification is for "Bid" and the other is for "BidUp". Anyway, @Hans is right when he says the property didn't change, and thus wouldn't require an UI update.

Answer (score 1):

Consider binding to a property that represents the actual value and then use a multibinding (i.e. currentValue and previousValue) to update your UI.

Comment: Alternatively, a single `Binding` against a new property that represents the delta between the previous and new `Bid` values, e.g., `BidChange`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel For the same reason `BidChange` will not work if bid change is `0.1` followed by another `0.1`; I need some way to force the notification to detect a change.