# For a custom TabControl how to remove the border if no items's left?

Tags: wpf

I have a TabControl which support delete items if needed. In order to make it look natural,I made the `TabItem` with a `0` bottom thickness and the `Content` with a `0` top thickness. Also I had

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource someLinearBrush with a 0.99 offset}" 
                    <!-- This is the area in which TabItems (the strips) will be drawn. -->
                    <TabPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                 </Border>
```

[image]

to imitate a line on the right side.[yellow line]
I also set a Icommand to do something like `List A.Remove(tab)` to remove tabs in the viewModel. My problem's When I delete every item inside, the ugly border background remains.[the yellow line]. I guess I need to do something like

```
private void OnCloseTab(object obj)
{
    TabData tab = obj as TabData;
    if (TabItems.Count() == 1)
    {
        //do sth to change the border background to transparent
    }
    Console.WriteLine("has been here ?");
    if (tab != null && TabItems.Contains(tab))
    {
        TabItems.Remove(tab);

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to reach the `Border` as everything's defined in the styles.xaml.

Comment: Where is that `Border` declared?  In the `TabControl` template?

Comment: this could be done using just pure XAML, I suppose the border is of the TabItems, some Trigger could listen to `Items.Count` to remove the border when needed.

Comment: @MikeStrobel In `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `TabControl` template, you could add a trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
  <Setter TargetName="YourBorder" Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Trigger>
```

Where `YourBorder` is an `x:Name` that you've given to your `Border`.  Note that since you reference a specific template element, this trigger must be placed in your `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, not your `Style.Triggers`.

Comment: Sir Could you help see my another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872179/binding-using-inotifypropertychanged ; basically I want to force trigger a `propertychanged` event to change a background whenever bid price changed; the problem is if bid price goes up followed by up, (or down down), It fails for obvious reasons.